# Reverse DNS lookups failing except when specifying my NS

Tags: domain-name-system, ptr-record

When trying to perform lookups on IP addresses within our IP space, I'm getting NXDOMAIN replies *unless* I specify my server directly (not just from the local network but from external nets as well, so no ACL issues). By specifying my server, I get correct reponses to queries. Could our ISP be preventing me from advertising our reverse DNS, since it's within a block they own (the ex-Savvis)? Since I am getting proper resolution directly, I'm thinking the configs are okay.

Comment: Sounds like they haven't delegated that zone to you.

Comment: Who is your ISP, you can typically email them

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your ISP did not explicitly delegated the range to you then this is expected behaviour. They are not "overwriting" your queries they simply do not acknowledge your existence. Reverse DNS resolution starts at the top domain, goes down through hierarchy and ends with whoever owns the IP address range.

If you purchased IP addresses from your ISP then they would add an NS record to their DNS delegating resolution of your range to your server. I have feeling that this is not your case, so they will never do such thing.

However, there may be another option for you. There are some nice ISPs out there that may give you rights to manage the range they leased to you on their own DNS server. You should check with your provider if they have/offer this feature.